# I can't update my database. symfony php database doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I try to manage my database with doctrine.

I have two entities voiture et modele, I succeeded to added modele after 3h. When I coded my entity `voiture` it keeps showing that the base is updated and there is no change.

My modele code:

```
<?php
/**
* Created by PhpStorm.
* User: jamel_pc
* Date: 2016-11-27
* Time: 9:16 PM
*/

namespace ParcBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Class Modele
* @package ParcBundle\Entity
*
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="Modele")
*/
class Modele{
/**
 *@ORM\Id
 *@ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
 *
 */

private $Libelle;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
 */

private $Pays;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
 */

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLibelle()
{
    return $this->Libelle;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $Libelle
 */
public function setLibelle($Libelle)
{
    $this->Libelle = $Libelle;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPays()
{
    return $this->Pays;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $Pays
 */
public function setPays($Pays)
{
    $this->Pays = $Pays;
}
}
```

and my voiture code:

```
<?php
/**
* Created by PhpStorm.
* User: jamel_pc
* Date: 2016-11-27
* Time: 11:10 PM
*/

/**
* Class voiture
* @package ParcBundle\Entity
*
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="Voiture")
*/

namespace ParcBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


class voiture
{

/**
 *@ORM\Id
 *@ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
 *
 */

private $Serie;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",length=255)
 */

private $DateMiseCirculation;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
 */
private $Marque;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ParcBundle\Entity\Modele" )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id");
 */
private $modele;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}
/**
 * @return mixed
 */

public function getModele()
{
    return $this->modele;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $modele
 */
public function setModele($id)
{
    $this->modele = $modele;
}


/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getSerie()
{
    return $this->Serie;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $Serie
 */
public function setSerie($Serie)
{
    $this->Serie = $Serie;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDateMiseCirculation()
{
    return $this->DateMiseCirculation;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $DateMiseCirculation
 */
public function setDateMiseCirculation($DateMiseCirculation)
{
    $this->DateMiseCirculation = $DateMiseCirculation;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getMarque()
{
    return $this->Marque;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $Marque
 */
public function setMarque($Marque)
{
    $this->Marque = $Marque;
}



}
```

This is the error I get :

> error : Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the
>   current entity metadata.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't separate annotation of the class declaration.

Comment: what is your current db schema?

Comment: krauze : i shouldn't seperate ? how that ?

Comment: sanandrl : mysql , and i have a base named "parc" and a table "modele"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because you are importing `ORM` after you have used it for your Entity annotation.

Try putting your Entity annotations below use `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM` like this:

```
<?php
/**
* Created by PhpStorm.
* User: jamel_pc
* Date: 2016-11-27
* Time: 11:10 PM
*/

namespace ParcBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Class voiture
* @package ParcBundle\Entity
*
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="Voiture")
*/


class voiture
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

 /.../

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two annotations for id field. Remove one of them:

```
/**
*@ORM\Id
*@ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/

/**
* @var integer
*
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
```